# ¿Porque no se mueve la imagen en java?

Tags: java, jframe

Me gustaría saber cual es el fallo de mi código que hace que el coche no se mueve.

```
 private void jLabel1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         int x, y;
        x = jLabel1.getX();
        y = jLabel1.getY();
        System.out.println(jLabel1.getLocation());//mostramos la posicion de la imagen

        switch (evt.getExtendedKeyCode()) {// captura las teclas
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x, y - 2);//arriba
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x, y + 2);//abajo
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x - 2, y);// derecha
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x + 2, y = 2); //izquierda
                break; // hace que la imagen se mueva con las teclas.
        }
    }
```

Por favor ayuda no encuentro el motivo todo va y se ejecuta bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo has movido, pero no le has indicado a la interfaz que debe dibujarlo en su nueva posición, para eso se usa el método `repaint()`, puedes leer más sobre cómo funciona el pintado de interfaces de usuario [aquí](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html), es un poco denso y está en inglés, pero vale la pena si te interesa optimizar estas cosas.

```
private void jLabel1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         int x, y;
        x = jLabel1.getX();
        y = jLabel1.getY();
        System.out.println(jLabel1.getLocation());//mostramos la posicion de la imagen

        switch (evt.getExtendedKeyCode()) {// captura las teclas
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x, y - 2);//arriba
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x, y + 2);//abajo
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x - 2, y);// derecha
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x + 2, y = 2); //izquierda
                break; // hace que la imagen se mueva con las teclas.
        }
    /*Dependiendo de si también estás cambiando tamaños, bordes, fuentes... 
    también es posible que necesites llamar a invalidate() para que vuelva a calcular
    cómo es y dónde debería estar de nuevo el elemento*/
    //Aquí, justo después de terminar de moverlo en la dirección que sea
    jLabel1.repaint();//repaint hace que vuelva a "repintarse" el elemento en la interfaz
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Siempre un placer. Para eso estamos aquí!

Comment: sigue sin moverse

Comment: ya lo soluciones